# "settled in as a Washingtonian" in Andrew's Brain by E. L. Doctorow

Tags: meaning, andrews-brain, e-l-doctorow

I'm reading Andrew's Brain by E. L. Doctorow. In this paragraph I have some difficulties:

> But the only job to be found was as a substitute science teacher at a
> D.C. high school. He took it. Within a month, one of the science
> teachers had a heart attack, and so there was Andrew with the pay of a
> substitute and the hours of a fulltimer. He found himself a studio
> apartment and **settled in as a Washingtonian**. It suited his sense of
> his life as a lost cause to have demoted himself from academia to a
> public high school.

I know **Washingtonian** means a native or inhabitant of Washington, but
I don't get the bolded phrase "**settled in as a Washingtonian**". Does anyone know its meaning?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In addition to verbose's answer, I think there's significance to the choice of phrasing "settled in as a Washingtonian" which goes beyond the meaning of "settle in" and "Washingtonian" individually.

Settling in means becoming familiar with somewhere new, and a Washingtonian is a native or inhabitant of Washington, as verbose and you said respectively. But, in context, Andrew "settl[ing] in as a Washingtonian" indicates more than just becoming familiar with a new city - he's **resigning himself to a new lifestyle**. Note the next sentence: "It suited his sense of his life as a lost cause to have demoted himself from academia to a public high school." He could have taken the high school job, "the only job to be found", with the mindset that it was a temporary position until he could find something better, but that wouldn't be settling in. Instead, he's resigned to considering himself "as a Washingtonian", rather than as someone taking a temporary job to tide himself over for a while. The phrase reflects **Andrew's mindset** as well as what he's physically doing.

Answer (score 5):

The Cambridge Dictionary defines **settle in** as follows:

> to become familiar with somewhere new, such as a new house, job, or school, and to feel comfortable and happy there:
> *Once we've settled in, we'll have you over for dinner.*

So the sentence means that Andrew got a new flat, worked at his new job, familiarized himself with Washington, and became used to the everyday routine of his life there.